# Error of build because of the error Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I have trouble related to Unexpected character of node module file.

Here is my `next.config.js` file

```
  /**
     * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
     */
    
    const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
    const path = require('path');
    
    const nextConfig = {
      /* config options here */
      webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
        if (!isServer) {
          config.resolve.fallback.fs = false;
          config.resolve.fallback.tls = false;
          config.resolve.fallback.net = false;
          config.resolve.fallback.dns = false;
        }
        return config;
      }
    }
    
    module.exports = {
      nextConfig,
      optimization: {
        minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
      },
      externals: {
        saslprep: require("saslprep"),
      },
      experimental: {
        forceSwcTransforms: true,
      },
      publicRuntimeConfig: {
        // for multimedia files
        staticFolder: "https://basic.am/static",
      },
      loaders: [{
        test: /.node?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      }]
    };
```

After the commannd `npm run build` I'm getting the following error.

```
warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
  - The root value has an unexpected property, nextConfig, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, trailingSlash, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).
  - The root value has an unexpected property, optimization, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, trailingSlash, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).
  - The root value has an unexpected property, externals, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, trailingSlash, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).
  - The root value has an unexpected property, loaders, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, trailingSlash, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (forceSwcTransforms) in next.config.js.
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.

info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd-darwin-x64/zstd.darwin-x64.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd-darwin-x64/zstd.darwin-x64.node
./node_modules/@mongodb-js/zstd/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/db.ts
./src/schema.ts
./src/apolloClient.ts

./node_modules/@napi-rs/snappy-darwin-x64/snappy.darwin-x64.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@napi-rs/snappy-darwin-x64/snappy.darwin-x64.node
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./src/db.ts
./src/schema.ts
./src/apolloClient.ts


> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

I have tried to add loaders, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding { test: /.txt$/, use: 'raw-loader' } to your next.config.js file.
I had the same error in my current project and it solved the issue for me